# What is the `(int)` after `return` means

Tags: c#, linq

```
  public static int SumDigits(int number)
  {
     return (int)number.ToString().Sum(x => char.IsNumber(x) ? char.GetNumericValue(x) : 0);
  }
```

What is the `(int)` after `return` means.

Its perfectly running, just need to understand it, thanks.

Comment: Another way to do that is `int sum = 0; while(number != 0) { sum += number % 10; number /= 10; } return sum;`  Although that will give you a negative result for a negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetNumericValue` method returns a `double`. The `(int)` is a cast that converts the returned `double` to `int`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netcore-3.1#System_Char_GetNumericValue_System_Char_

Keep in mind that it truncates the decimal part which should be okay for numeric char values. There are methods like `Convert.ToInt32(doubleValue)` or `(int) Math.Round(doubleValue)` that round the result instead of truncating it.